# How to use into out file query in Amazon RDS

Tags: php, mysql, database, amazon-rds

I am trying to import a CSV from a database. My query was working great with my localhost. Now I'm using Amazon RDS Server and it's not working; is there any way to grant file permission in Amazon RDS user privilege?

My current query is this :

```
$path = getcwd() . '/uploads/data.csv' ;
    $sql = "SELECT 'Name', 'Email', 'Type of inquiry' , 'Message'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT `engine4_mytable_contacts`.name ,
            `engine4_mytable_contacts`.email, 
            `engine4_mytable_contacts`.topic,
            `engine4_mytable_contacts`.feed_back
            FROM engine4_mytable_contacts WHERE contact_date >= '$prevDate' into outfile '$path' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   ENCLOSED BY '\"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r'";

$result = $connection->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
```

How can I alternatively run this query using PHP?

Comment: Stop concatenating the variables in SQL query. Visit https://lampheap.com/prevent-sql-injection/ to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: okay thanks but I am searching the way to export from amazon rds database please help

Comment: Please show us the PHP code you've written.

Comment: okay I have added just running this query works in local host

Comment: RDS does not support INFILE/OUTFILE statement. Read this question please. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007523/how-to-export-sql-output-directly-to-csv-on-amazon-rds

Comment: yes  but you can use INFILE using LOCAL IN FILE

Answer (score 0):

I have found the only solution to do this using php is like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `engine4_mytbl_contacts`.name ,
        `engine4_mytbl_contacts`.email, 
        `engine4_mytbl_contacts`.topic,
        `engine4_mytbl_contacts`.feed_back
        FROM engine4_mytbl_contacts WHERE contact_date >= '$prevDate'";

        $result = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();
        $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $file = fopen($path, "w"); // this will open the file and erase all datas
        foreach($rows as $val){
            $array = array($val->name,$val->email,$val->topic,$val->feed_back);
            fputcsv($file,$array);
        }
```